# Dump all segments from nutch

Tags: apache, nutch

I am simply trying to dump my segments from a crawl using readseg.  If I only have one folder the command

```
bin/nutch readseg -dump crawl/segments/* dumpFolder
```

works, but if I have multiple segment folders it fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give the path of segment till the segments dir(the one with the timestamp). If you want to read all the segments in the segments/ dir, you could have a wrapper class where you can list contents in the segments dir and call readseg from there.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, here is what you can try

Merge all segments first:

```
bin/nutch mergesegs crawl/merged crawl/segments/*
```

Then dump merged segment

```
bin/nutch readseg -dump crawl/merged/* dumpedContent
```

Answer (score 0):

To read segments content from sequence files and create individual files on files:

#### 1. Merge segments

this command creates `mergedseg` by combining all the segments in `segments/*`

```
nutch mergesegs mergedseg -dir segments/
```

#### 2. Dump the merged segment

this command should be creating files under `content_dump`

```
nutch dump -segment mergedseg -outputDir content_dump
```

> ### Notes
>
> - Tested in version 1.10
> - The `nutch dump` seems to be bit tricky. It didn't dump when I gave path of segment. In the above example `mergedseg` is a parent directory of segment directory.
> - You can also dump specific mimeTypes. Check help of `nutch dump`